# How to extend ganglia?

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, bigdata, ganglia

**After I installed the ganglia, the web UI just show the basic metric information about disk, as follows:**

[image]

**But in the ganglia demo website, [please see here](http://ganglia.wikimedia.org/latest/?r=hour&cs=&ce=&m=disk_total&c=Analytics%20cluster%20eqiad&h=analytics1015.eqiad.wmnet&tab=m&vn=&hide-hf=false&mc=2&z=medium&metric_group=NOGROUPS), it show many metrics about disk iostat, as follows:**
[image]
**There is my question: How should I config ganglia to show these metrics?**

I know there are many ganglia module on the github, but I don't konw how to use it. I'm a newbie to ganglia, can you tell me how should I do? Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to access each of the nodes.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you explain carefully？@LokeshA.R.

Answer (score 1):

2 Steps to show Spark metrics in ganglia:

1. **Rebuild** spark with ganglia support

   Spark pre-release doesn't come with ganglia support for license issue, Spark's Apache 2.0 and ganglia's LGPL.

   Normally, `build/mvn -Pspark-ganglia-lgpl -Pother_profiles_to_enable -DskipTests clean package` should be OK to rebuild one yourself, you can find more info on customizing spark build [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html)
2. **Set up** metrics using `conf/metrics.properties`

   I would suggest reading [Monitoring and Instrumentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) and [metrics configuration template](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/conf/metrics.properties.template) first.

   > The metrics system is divided into **instances** which correspond to internal components. **Each instance can be configured to report its metrics to one or more sinks**. Accepted values for [instance] are "master", "worker", "executor", "driver", and "applications".
   >
   > A "sink" specifies where metrics are delivered to. Each instance can be assigned one or more sinks.

ganglia is one of the sinks, and you could configure it as follows:

```
*.sink.ganglia.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GangliaSink
*.sink.ganglia.host=239.2.11.71
*.sink.ganglia.port=8636
*.sink.ganglia.period=10
*.sink.ganglia.unit=seconds
*.sink.ganglia.ttl=1
*.sink.ganglia.mode=multicast
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explain, But I want to know how to config ganglia to show the disk io(**the result of commond iostat**)?

Comment: @gwgyk, I make the answer because you tag it as `apache-spark`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, because I thank the problem is adapted to the spark cluster. Could you tell me, if I want to extend the ganglia, how should I do?